# Postgresql function return different tables depending on cell value?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I have a table called

```
foo_table(id, table_name, row_id);  values (1, test1, 3), (2, test1, 4), (3, test2, 2);
```

I want to return functon foo_f(table_name);
so it would return all data from origin table AS

```
select * FROM test1 where id IN(select row_id FROM foo_table where table_name = $1);
```

or is there a way to join it inside a function.

the point is `foo_table` may contain 8 different tables and everytable has a different layout

Comment: Are you trying to build a dynamic query. In which case you want to look at plpgsql's EXECUTE (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: I want to return setof rows that has no special. Meaning, I don't want to pre define column type or names. I would like to return 1 spesific table set and I would get that table name from foo_table and all row_id's from it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think your best option is actually to do a `UNION` with a where clause which ensures that only one branch gets run.  You would have to pull an identically structured subset (in terms of data types, but note you can cast and name `NULL` values).  The planner is pretty smart and will only run the relevant portions of the plan.  For example consider this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION journals()
RETURNS setof .... LANGUAGE SQL AS $$;
 SELECT jl.*, j.reference, j.description, j.counterparty
   FROM journal_line jl
   JOIN journals js ON jl.entry_id = js.id
   JOIN (select id, reference, description, null::text as counterparty, 
                'general' as type 
           FROM general_journal
          UNION
         select id, invnumber, description, counterparty, 'sales'
           FROM sales_journal) j ON (j.type, j.id) = (js.type, js.id);
 $$;
```

Now in 9.3 you can get some mileage out of LATERAL here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION journals()
RETURNS setof .... LANGUAGE SQL AS $$;
 SELECT jl.*, j.reference, j.description, j.counterparty
   FROM journal_line jl
   JOIN journals js ON jl.entry_id = js.id
   JOIN (select id, reference, description, null::text as counterparty
           FROM general_journal
          WHERE js.type = 'general'
          UNION
         select id, invnumber, description, counterparty
           FROM sales_journal
          WHERE js.type = 'sales') j ON j.id = js.id
 $$;
```

If that doesn't work, use `EXECUTE ... USING`

The planner usually is smart enough to properly optimize this assuming proper indexing.